# Javascript replace function with tagged template strings

Tags: javascript, tagged-templates

I've been reading Javascript for Hackers by Gareth Heyes and I've come across a piece of code I can't wrap my head around:

```
'a'.replace.call`1${/./}${alert}`
```

I get that the call function will assign "this" to be "1," and the first argument to the replace function will be the regex. The regex will match and the second argument will be the reference to the alert function.

What I don't understand is how "this" (which the call function sets to be "1,") gets changed back to the window object for alert to be able to successfully execute. I also don't understand how 1 gets passed to the alert function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: effectively, the code that is executed is `'a'.replace.call(["1",,], /./, alert)` does that help you understand? `alert` is just a callback function for the replace function ... the `this` for `.replace` has no bearing on it

Comment: "*call function will assign "this" to be "1,"*" - it will assign that only for `replace`, but not for `alert`

Comment: Thank you both, that clears up a lot of my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the evaluation table, step by step:

| Step | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `` 'a'.replace.call`1${/./}${alert}` `` | N/A |
| `'a'.replace.call(['1', '', ''], /./, alert)` | [Tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) expansion |
| `'a'.replace.call('1,,', /./, alert)` | String conversion applied by `.replace()` |
| `'1,,'.replace(/./, match => alert(match))` | It's technically `(...args) => alert(...args)`, but `alert()` ignores all arguments other than the first. |
| `alert('1')` | `/./` matches once, and `1` is the content of that match. |

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you so much!